# What's the best way to deserialize Anchor Account Data from AccountInfo?

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang, deserialization

I have struct `MyAccount` that I want to deserialize from a list of `ctx.remaining_accounts`. What's the best way of doing this?

Currently I'm using the following format, copied from [jet protocol v2's line here](https://github.com/jet-lab/jet-v2/blob/3f9451e6320f49b9cbe492b350cb94b3647c70c6/programs/margin/src/adapter.rs#L170)

```
let account_info = &ctx.remaining_accounts[0];
let account_data = &mut &**account_info.try_borrow_mut_data()?;
let mut my_account = MyAccount::try_deserialize(account_data).unwrap();
```

Curious what the best practice is.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup a rust client.

1. Create new cargo package inside your program root directory. And make sure to import your program in your client package (Cargo.toml)
2. Create new solana client

```
    let payer = Keypair::new();
    let client = Client::new(payer, "http://localhost:8899".into());
```

3. get the data slice and deserialize using the program Account

```
    let mut data: &[u8] = &client.get_account_data(&pubkey).unwrap();
    let some_account = my_program::SomeAccount::try_deserialize(&mut data).unwrap();
    print!("{:?}", some_account);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some people prefer the [..] syntax vs the double deref (both are confusing, imo). You might also use the `?` operator over unwrap:

```
    let buf: &[u8] = &ctx.remaining_accounts[0].try_borrow_mut_data()?[..];
    let acc: Whatever = Whatever::try_deserialize(&mut buf)?;
```